# Google Places componentrestrictions Country for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-places-api, google-places

Currently I am using the following javascript on our web site to restrict searches to the US which works fine.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autoAddress')), {types: ['geocode'],componentRestrictions: {country: 'US'}
});
```

I have hunted around trying to find a way of again limiting searches to a Country for our iPhone app but no luck. componentRestrictions: {country: 'US'} does the trick in javascript but I cannot seem to find the equivalent in iOS.

Currently I am using the code from the following example which seems to be pretty standard and works well as is ;

```
https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the latest version (1.11.0) of the Google Places API for iOS?  This was added in that release (see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/releases#version_1110_-_december_2015)).

With 1.11.0 this is done by setting the `country` property on [`GMSAutocompleteFilter`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_filter).

Comment: Excellent  thank you for that. Can't up vote yet sorry.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Also you may be able to accept the answer even if you can't upvote.